# AnyChart: Fit to include annotation line at price

Tags: annotations, candlestick-chart, anychart

I have a candlestick chart, and would like to draw an annotation line at a price that is just below the visible area of the chart.

How do I adjust the scale to get make the line visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply the scale [minimum](https://api.anychart.com/anychart.scales.Linear#minimum) or [maximum](https://api.anychart.com/anychart.scales.Linear#maximum). Or apply appropriate [scale gaps](https://docs.anychart.com/Stock_Charts/Scales#gaps) to let the annotation be visible.